# How to use a column name as part of string pattern and replacement string in Replace() statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to replace a string in a column which includes values that comes from another column. The code below is what I envisaged could be possible but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT  
    REPLACE(m1.MovieDescription,'/img/movie/'+m1.MovieID,'/img/film/'+f1.FilmID)
FROM 
    Movie m1
INNER JOIN
    Film f1  
    ON f1.MovieID = m1.MovieID
```

The `MovieID` and `FilmID` values are unique for each row. Is there a way to achieve the above or do I need to resort to dynamic sql statement with a cursor?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  What is the issue with your query?

Comment: Would `replace(replace(m1.MovieDescription, m.MovieID,f.FilmID ),'/img/movie/','/img/film/')` not have worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be fine, if that is what you want to do.  If the ids are numbers, use `CONCAT()` instead of `+` to avoid a type conversion error:

```
SELECT REPLACE(m1.MovieDescription,
               CONCAT('/img/movie/', m.MovieID),
               CONCAT('/img/film/', f.FilmID)
              )
FROM Movie m JOIN INNER JOIN
     Film f1 
     ON f.MovieID = m.MovieID;
```

Comment: Yes it was a type conversion problem. Concat seems to have worked thank you